# If $g(x)=x+2$ and $f(x) = 2\arctan(x),$Then integers satisfying $(f(g(x)))^2-5f(g(x))+4>0\;,$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x) = 2\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $g(x)$ be a differentiable function satisfying
>
> $\displaystyle g\left(\frac{x+2y}{3}\right)=\frac{g(x)+2g(y)}{3}\;\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $g'(0)=1$ and $g(0)=2.$
>
> Then number of integers values of $x$ satisfying $(f(g(x)))^2-5f(g(x))+4>0\;,$

where $x\in (-10,10)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given  $\displaystyle g\left(\frac{x+2y}{3}\right)=\frac{g(x)+2g(y)}{3}.$

Now differentiate both side w r to $x$ and $y$ as a constant, We get

$\displaystyle g'\left(\frac{x+2y}{3}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{g'(x)}{3}...................(\star)$

And differentiate both side w r to $y$ and $x$ as a constant, We get

$\displaystyle g'\left(\frac{x+2y}{3}\right)\cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{2g'(y)}{3}..................(\star\star)$

So from these two equation, We get $\displaystyle g'(x)=g'(y) = k$ (Let we assume )

So above given $g'(0)=1.$ So we get $g'(0) = k=1$

So $\displaystyle g'(x) = 1\Rightarrow \int g'(x)dx = \int 1dx\Rightarrow g(x)=x+c$

above given $g(0) = 2.$ So we get $g(0)=c=2$

So we get $g(x) = x+2$

Now Solving $(f(g(x)))^2-5f(g(x))+4>0\Rightarrow \left[f(g(x))-1\right]\cdot \left[f(g(x))-4\right]>0$

So we get $f(g(x))<1$ or $f(g(x))>4$

So $2\tan^{-1}(x+2)<1$ or $2\tan^{-1}(x+2)>4$

So we get $\displaystyle x<\tan(0.5)-2$ or $x>\tan(2)-2$

Now how can i solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: "then number of integers" = ?